# Meaning of Old Babylonian word pāqidūtum

Tags: grammar, translation, akkadian, babylonian

I am learning the Old Babylonian language and just stumbled  over the word/form *pāqidūtum*. It seems to be a third person male stativ singular + u + the female ending tum of the verb paqadum (to care for), but that does not make any sense to me. Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: No one can help you without a context.

Comment: @fdb I wish I could add some context. its a word that occurs in an exercise (the exercise just consists of single words which have to be translated). in the chapter the stativ and suboridnate clauses were introduced so i think it has something to do with these, but i still cant determine the grammatical form

Comment: What exercise is it? (As in, what book is it from, etc?)

Comment: @Draconis its on page 48, exercise A.4 of the following script https://www.assyriologie.uni-muenchen.de/studium_lehre/hinweise/akkadisch_mit_keilschrift1.pdf 
the script is in german though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pāqidūtu(m) is the nominative plural of pāqidu(m), the active participle of the verb paqādu “to entrust etc.”

(In theory it could also be an abstract noun in -ūtu, as suggested in the other reply, but such a word, if it existed, would have merited a separate entry in the lexica. Also, the fact that the author does not introduce this suffix until a later lesson indicates that he would not expect students to know it at this point.)

Comment: thank you very much! is the t indicating that it is a female nominative?

Comment: @maxE. No. Adjectives have the masculine plural ending -ūtu instead of -ū.

Answer (score 4):

The word *pāqidūtum* is not listed in the [CAD](https://oi.uchicago.edu/research/publications/assyrian-dictionary-oriental-institute-university-chicago-cad), which suggests that it's likely not historically attested. But the word *pāqidu(m)* = "provider, overseer, caretaker", also included in the exercise you cited, *is* listed on CAD volume 12 (P) page 137.

One page 35 of [the lecture notes you linked](https://www.assyriologie.uni-muenchen.de/studium_lehre/hinweise/akkadisch_mit_keilschrift1.pdf), you will also find the abstractifying suffix *-ūtum*, used to derive abstract terms for "the state of being something" (and sometimes collectives like "all somethings") from concrete nouns, such as *šarrūtum* = "kingship" from *šarrum* = "king" or *awīlūtum* = "humanity, mankind" from *awīlum* = "(free) man, person".

Thus, by analogy, *pāqidūtum* can be fairly regularly and transparently analyzed as "providership" or "the role of a *pāqidum*".